# Shopify APIs for User Management

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, user-management

I am creating providers using Terraform in Go language. Please tell me if there are Shopify APIs available for user management, i.e., I want to create, update, delete, activate, and deactivate users using Shopify APIs, so just let me know if it is available.

Comment: https://community.shopify.com/c/Storefront-API-SDKs/Shopify-APIs-for-User-Management/m-p/1202367/highlight/true#M1276